# in R: remove rows containing no integer (such as characters i.e.) from a data frame

Tags: r, row

My data frame df looks like follow:

```
Variable A Variable B Variable C
9          2          1
2          0          don't know
maybe      1          1
?          0          3
```

I need to remove all rows, where non-numerical values are used. It should look like this afterwards:

```
Variable A Variable B Variable C
9          2          1
```

I thought about something like

```
df[! grepl(*!= numerical*, df),]
```

or

```
df[! df %in% *!= numerical*, ]
```

but I don't find anything I could use as input for "take all that doesn't match numerical values". Could you please help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to loop through the columns, convert to `numeric` so that all non-numeric elements convert to NA, check for NA with `is.na` , negate (`!`) it, compare the corresponding elements of `list` with `Reduce`  and `&`, use that to subset the rows.

```
df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, function(x) !is.na(as.numeric(x)))),]
```

Comment: I was thinking `df[] = sapply(df, as.numeric)` and then `na.exclude(df)` - does that have disadvantages compared to your `Reduce` approach?

Comment: @jakub, the only disadvantage I see to your approach is it returns a `matrix` object instead of a `data.frame`.

Comment: @jakub For the `sapply`, approach, you get a `matrix` as Benjamin mentioned.  For big datasets, it can be a memory issue.

Comment: @akrun actually, if I call it with brackets `df[] =`, I get a `data.frame` with the original name. My intuition was that this rewrites the object in place, thus saving memory. But that is incorrect, true?

Comment: @jakub The `[]` preserves the structure, but i guess the matrix on the rhs would still be created (if I am not wrong)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to do it, but works.

s is the df that contains your data-

```
contains <-  lapply(seq_len(nrow(s)), function(i){
    yes <-  grep("[^0-9.]" , s[i,]) #regex for presence of non-digits 
    ifelse(identical(yes, integer(0)),F,T)
}) %>% unlist


 s <- s[which(!contains),]
```

Thanks!